# How to add spacing between each Item in list view

Tags: java, android

I just created a simple custom list view and I want to add spacing between each item in list View I already added vertical spacing attribute but there's no spacing yet this is my xml file for list view

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer.fragments.LVMenuFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:verticalSpacing="20dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

and this is listitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/menuRL"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/listviewborder">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/itemImage"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/menulistTV2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/itemImage"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/qtyID"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/minusBtn"
            android:background="@drawable/qty_border">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtQTY"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="30dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/minusBtn"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/minus_borders"
            android:text="-"
            android:textSize="40dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: In listitem add matginTop and marginBottom.

Comment: @Rajasekhar thanks alot please post your answer to have a check and rate I gonna try this

Comment: attach your screen shot ,what you got right now.@Dev.7arooney

Comment: It works great with margin bottom I gonna attach an Image now @Radhey

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
android:dividerHeight="20dp"
```

in ListView

Comment: do you really think it will give spacing between listview items just because of #divider height !@Nabil

Comment: it is #patch :)

Comment: yes, it will give spacing between listview items just because of #divider height

Answer (score 0):

```js
  <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:marigin_bottom="5dp";
        android:verticalSpacing="20dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution

1. In listitem add margin

   ```
           <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
               android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
               android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
               android:orientation="vertical">
           <TextView/>
           <TextView/>
           </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. For First and Last Item add margin in Listview

   ```
              <Listview 
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
               android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
              />
   ```